# Notification Templating with WebHooks default payload (Appveyor)

Tags: appveyor

So currently I am in the process of setting up notifications, and what I had wanted to send in my message portion was the url for the artifact zip file that was created.

I took a look at the default payload (https://www.appveyor.com/docs/notifications/#webhook-payload-default) and was able to send {{jobs}} which gave me in the email this:
                  **System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Appveyor.Models.BuildJobNotificationTemplateData]**

I figured I could traverse this in my messaging template. However, when I tried to do that it kept erroring out with different methods that I’ve tried.

Some of them include :

```
           {{jobs[0].artifacts[0].url}}
            {{jobs.artifacts.url}}
            {{eventData.jobs.artifacts.url}}
            {{eventData.jobs[0].artifacts[0].url}}
            Etc…
```

What would the proper syntax be to grab the first artifacts url using the templating engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax will work (see [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) template to understand the syntax)

```
<p>Artifacts:</p>
    <ul>
    {{#jobs}}
      {{#artifacts}}
        <li>{{url}}</li>
      {{/artifacts}}
    {{/jobs}}
    </ul>
```

But unfortunately it will return temporary Azure blob storage URL, which will expire in 60 minutes. Please watch https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1646. For now to get permanent URL please use [this workaround](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/7031-notification-link-to-artifact-expires#comment_42930510)